# How to set fixed background position from right side in css?

Tags: css

In this case

```
li {background: url("../img/grey-arrow-next.png") no-repeat right center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D4E8EB}
```

I want `20px` space in right side before to background image and I can't give margin on `li` because `border` should touch the edges.

So I need to set `20px` but it takes `20px` from left side not right side.

```
li {background: url("../img/grey-arrow-next.png") no-repeat 20px center;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #D4E8EB}
```

Comment: can't think of a way other than using js to calculate the width of the element, subtracting "20 + width of background image", and pushing the background image that pixels to the right from the left. not very elegant... not at all.

Comment: Maybe you should choose one of the answers if the question has been answered satisfactorily.

Answer (score 83):

in your css mention position right then "spacing value(50px)" then other position(center/top)

```
li {background: url("../img/grey-arrow-next.png") no-repeat right 50px center;
border-bottom: 1px solid #D4E8EB}
```

**Older Browser and IE8 and old version of IE does not support this code.** Latest updated browsers has no conflicts with this method and hopefully future updates will support it too.

If you are using modern browser, try `background-position: calc(100% - 50px) center;` as suggested in another answer too. `calc` has long way to go as it is logically and mathematically capable to produce much accurate result.

Comment: That's pretty awesome. I had no idea you could compound values like that.

Comment: This doesn't work in Windows Safari.

Comment: This is awesome, why is this not a documented feature?

Comment: This actually created whitespace on the right for me. I used a percentage value instead of the pixel value.

Comment: Just for completion: Doesn't work in IE8 too, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142405/offset-a-background-image-from-the-right-using-css

Answer (score 43):

You can use the CSS3 "calc" function:

example:

```
background-position: calc(100% - 10px) center;
```

Comment: This works in all modern browsers - IE8 and below are unsupported (http://caniuse.com/calc). Be aware that you may get undesired results using calc in a CSS preprocessor, without escaping the calculation.  For example `Less` processes `calc(100% - 10px)` as `calc(90%)`, unless written as `~"calc(100% - 10%)"`.

Comment: In IE7 and lower you can solve this with `expression`s, in IE8 you're pretty much stuck.

Comment: @JohnCatterfeld It's worth noticing for if anyone is just skimming your comment that '~"calc(100% - 10%)"' == 'calc(90%)'; you're probably looking for '~"calc(100% - 10px)"' when using LESS.

Comment: @JohnCatterfeld works perfectly, however any idea how to stop Visual Studio from complaining about invalid properties when doing this without flat out turning errors off? ~"calc(100% - 10px)" is not valid property for background-position. Its only a warning but still sooner it did not appear

Answer (score 10):

Just add 20px blank space to the image right side in a graphic editor.

Comment: This is an easiest option to go with! however I believe that this is not the only way!

Comment: This is a very ugly approach.

Comment: @MarvinRabe Suggest something better.

Comment: How about what the highest rated answer says?

Comment: Today better solution is using `calc`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16845269/1447182

Comment: Cross-browser awesome solution, one up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use other object inside li tag, and give it your background image with a margin-right:

```
li #image {
    margin-right: 20px;
    background: url(pp.jpg) no-repeat right center;
}

li {
    border: 1px solid #D4E8EB;
}
```

Comment: but i can't use background image with `#image`. because the background image i need vertically centered always and there are other elements also inside the `li`

Answer (score 1):

use the following code to add 20px to the **right** of the background-image --

```
li {background: url("../img/grey-arrow-next.png") no-repeat right center;
border-bottom: 1px solid #D4E8EB; padding-right:20px}
```

use the following code to add 20px to the **left** of the background-image --

```
li {background: url("../img/grey-arrow-next.png") no-repeat right center;
border-bottom: 1px solid #D4E8EB; padding-left:20px}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
border-right: 20px solid transparent;
```

Answer (score -1):

place a span tag within the `<li>` and add the margin to that, that way your `<li>` should still stretch to the edge along with your border.

Comment: but if i add padding to `ul` the `border` also leave that space which I don't want.

Comment: I've edited to answer to be closer to what you need.

Comment: but the background image i can't use on `span`

Comment: yes you can, just use display: block;

Answer (score -1):

unfortunately the 'easy' solution is edit your image and add 20px right and bottom of transparent space.

you could achieve it with background-clip / background-origin probably but that'd take a bit of playing with...

Comment: I'm using same image at many place but I think editing the image for one case would be ok, if there is no other solution