# Is it possible on CSS(2) say right-5 on background-position?

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Offset a background image from the right using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142405/offset-a-background-image-from-the-right-using-css)

CSS usually is :

```
background-position:right top;
```

but If I'd like to say somethings like right-5px? Is it possible?
Like position in an element :

```
right:-5px;
```

Anyone know?

**EDIT**

Maybe it is unclear! I mean somethings like :

```
background-position:right-5px top;
```

Comment: background-position:-5px 0px;  ?

Comment: -5px start from left! I need -5px from right :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142405/offset-a-background-image-from-the-right-using-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with `CSS2` but you can do a trick. Write like this:

```
div{
    background:red;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
div:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    top:0;
    right:-5px;
    background:url('http://www.dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff');
}
```

Check this  http://jsfiddle.net/s9L2T/

Comment: not true, css3 has an advanced background module. Check it out (link in my answer) for more info.

Comment: My answer related to css2 not css3. OP clear explain "is it possible in CSS2"

Comment: hehe, you edited your answer before commenting;) First you wrote "not possible with CSS". But nevermind, your workaround works (However not in IE<=7)

Comment: I edit because i don't want next time any one come & say the same thing :)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html#propdef-background-position

As of CSS2.1 specs, you only can do this if you know the dimensions of the container.

Assume container is 300px. you can either say:

`background-position:305px` or use percentages.

**However**,

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-position

as of the css3 specs, you can define the offsets from all different corners.

So `background-position: top 0 right -5px;` would give your desired result.

Except IE, **[Support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts)** is quite good.

Comment: I can't see any ways on doing this :O

Comment: But it always start from left in count px! not from right!

Comment: Css3, I need on css (i mind about IE) :)

Comment: @markzzz than use a second container (either a div or :after which is not supported in IE7 though) which is shifted 5px to the right.