# How to clip the container by a fixed distance from its right edge?

Tags: css, css-shapes, clip-path

Just as in [Offset a background image from the right using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142405/offset-a-background-image-from-the-right-using-css) I want to position my `shape` some absolute value relative to the right edge of the container.

```
clip-path: polygon(0 0, right 1em 0, 100% 50%, right 1em 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
```

This should cut a triangle from the element on the right, which is 1em long.

I cannot use % because then the triangle size would depend on the length of the element, which I don't want.

Unfortunately it does not work this way. Is there another solution?

Comment: I must warn you this clip-path method don't work on firefox; you can get the cross-browsers code building it [**here on this link**](http://cssplant.com/clip-path-generator)

Comment: If there's no solution with clip-path, you can translateX it by 100% or create a mirror one and set transform-origin on the right edge + scaleX(-1) or similar :)

Comment: @FelipeAls this sounds interesting – but how do you actually do that? The shape contains text, so mirroring it wouldn't work I guess?

Comment: Ah yes, or you'd have to mirror a second time the elements containing text...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use the `calc` function to subtract `1em` from `100%` to achieve the required effect. Doing it this way would mean that the points would always be `1em` from the right edge of the container and it wouldn't depend on the element's length.

There is no other way to do this with `clip-path`. Unlike `background-image`, these do not take a side as a reference.

```css
div{
  height: 40vh;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 1em) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 1em) 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);  
  background: red;
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Hei thanks for the rectangle tipp, of course I meant triangle (:

Comment: That's genius, thanks.